# How to get Azure tenant name from graph.microsoft.com?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I need to discover user's tenant name, since the service endpoint, resourceId that I'll be using an Azure service that requires me to specify the tenant name:

service endpoint:  https://[tenantnamme].api.crm.dynamics.com/...
   resource Id:  https://[tenantname].crm.dynamics.com

I was hoping Unified Microsoft Graph API can discover this for me.  I looked at the documentation, the closest I can see is to use
       graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization
which will give me back: 
   verifiedDomains : [
                      ....
                      "name" : "contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
                    ]

But, I'm not sure if this is the right approach.  What if an org has multiple verified domains? Does verified domain name is the same as tenant name?

Update: This is my real scenario. I have a web app that allows user to authenticate to Azure AD via OAuth2.  I have no problem obtaining refresh token and access token from OAuth interactions.  However, in other to use other service, it requires [azure-ad-tenant-name] in their service end point.  That's my question coming from.

Answer (score 7):

I believe that you're on the right track with the **graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/organization** endpoint. You should be able to find the tenant name in the **verifiedDomains** list. The entry that should contain domain with the tenant name is the initial domain:

```
{
    ...
    "isInitial": true,
    "name": "contoso.onmicrosoft.com",
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Same. When you create a AD, you will obtain a domain name and a tenant id without tenant name, they are both the unique identifier of a AD. Use `Get-AzureRmTenant` to get all tenantid and domains in your subscription.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm not looking for Powershell solution.  I'm looking for REST solution, which we will implement on opensource solutions

Comment: If you can obtain access token that indicate your tenant has been created,  you only need to hardcoding your tenant id to [azure-ad-tenant-name], because every access token do not have more than one tenant id.

Comment: Ok. If you need tenant name(domain name) using API, use the Grapgh API: `https://graph.windows.net/tenantid/domains?api-version=beta`,hope it helps you.

Comment: There's also a Nuget package that can help you out with the Graph API, take a look at `Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient`