# C# Get Tenant Name API

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, postman

Is there's a way or API to get the tenant name or directory name? Hoping to pass a tenant Id because in this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tenants/list it only returning tenantID.

Thanks!

Comment: ID is a child of tenantID.  What is the inner text that is actually being returned?

Comment: Is there a reason you want to use the tenant name instead of tenant id? Both of them serve the same purpose.

Comment: it is returning just the same.
"id": "/tenants/1111-1111-1111-111-1111",
"tenantId": "1111-1111-1111-111-1111"

Comment: I need to display them on my projects, thats y.

Comment: See if this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36461956/how-to-get-azure-tenant-name-from-graph-microsoft-com.

Comment: the link has no answer on how to.

Comment: I've asked for this before from the product team. AFAIK it's not available.

Comment: So its not possible? I can get all the tenant Ids, is theres a way to pass TenantId as a parameter to get the tenant name?